# Using vnet_subnet_id to bring up the AKS cluster through terraform - Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create an AKS cluster using terraform.I'm using the `vnet_subnet_id` parameter in the `default_node_pool` block - so the Kubernetes nodes come up in the subnet id that i pass here.
However, i would want to also conditionally be able to create the kubernetes cluster in the normal way, that is, without using the `vnet_subnet_id` parameter(As this is parameter is only optional).This way it just brings up the Kubernetes nodes in the Vnet/subnet that are part of the `node resource group(usual way)

```
 default_node_pool {
        name = "${var.name}"
        vm_size = "${var.aks_node_type}"
        vnet_subnet_id = "${var.subnetid}"
     }
```

Is it possible to execute a condition and implement both the scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

sure, use something like this:

```
vnet_subnet_id = var.condition == "something" ? var.subnetid : null
```

and then based on this condition it will either put it into your subnetid or create a new one

Comment: Okay @4c74356b41, I just tried this.And i got this error.
`invalid variable syntax: "null". Did you mean 'var.null'? If this is part of inline `template` parameter then you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs. For
example: ${a} becomes $${a}`
I'm using - 
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.azurerm v1.39.0

This is what i tried with -  vnet_subnet_id = "${var.subcheck == "true" ? var.subnetid : null}"

Comment: oh lol. with 0.11 I'm not sure you have conditional syntax at all, you should upgrade 10 0.13 (or at least 0.12) and use azurerm 2+, the stuff you are using is heavily outdated